# Proposed [specific-incident] / [specific-accident] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging, burninate-tag

There are currently a few tags in use relating to specific incidents, e.g. [mh370-incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mh370-incident), [us1549-incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us1549-incident), [tam3054-incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tam3054-incident) and [lot16-incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lot16-incident).

There were also a number of others that I created and added to questions, following suit with the other tags. These were edited out by a user a week or 2 ago (not too sure why given the precedent, but I didn't mention it).

Thing is, these tags *do* create a bit of a mess, especially if there is only 1 question with that tag. Other questions related to specific accidents are being asked frequently though, for example: [How did flight 2574 break up?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/how-did-flight-2574-break-up).

I propose that we create a [specific-incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-incident) tag that all of these - and any future questions - can be lumped into. A [specific-accident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-accident) tag synonym can be added.

There are [21 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*-incident) still tagged with `*-incident`. I can find the questions I'd previously added tags to - I'd guess there'd be another 15.

Is this something the community agrees or disagrees with?

Answer (score 4):

We already have [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents) and [incidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incidents) tags; I don't see what adding the `specific-` prefix buys us. It gives no additional information, doesn't help people find or categorize questions or answers, and people who come to the site are *very* unlikely to add that tag to their question.

You can argue that we shouldn't have tags specific to individual events, but I don't see what harm it's doing. There may be people who want to follow them, or easily search for them.